# What does gl.bindBuffer and gl.bufferData do?

Tags: webgl

I am making my way through some simple WebGL tutorials in which the order of operations is:

1. Create an array of vertices
2. Populate a buffer with those vertices
3. Define a vertex and fragment shader
4. etc

In the second step, I find these lines of code:

```
const buffer = gl.createBuffer()
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer)
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertexData), gl.STATIC_DRAW)
```

The MDN docs for the two are not enlightening:

- bindBuffer: "binds a given WebGLBuffer to a target."
- bufferData: "initializes and creates the buffer object's data store."

My questions are:

- What is binding? What is a target? Why would one do this?
- What is a data store?

Comment: `bufferData` transfers the data into the GPU memory.

Comment: [What is a target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/bindBuffer#parameters)

Answer (score 0):

You would like to send the vertex data directly to the buffer, but in WebGL you have to use an intermediary - the target.

So you create the buffer, then bind it to the target ARRAY_BUFFER. Now you can upload the vertex data to the target ARRAY_BUFFER and it will go to the buffer that is currently bound to that target.

A good explanation can be found here [WebGL 2: Objects, Targets & Binding](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sWBt5WrQTfE&list=PLPbmjY2NVO_X1U1JzLxLDdRn4NmtxyQQo&index=7&ab_channel=AndrewAdamson)